# Manipulating map tile data to align with raster data in R

Tags: r, raster, rgl

I'm trying to plot map tiles on a 3D surface using rgl and cannot figure out how to align the data correctly.  This is probably related to R's behaviour of adding a 90 degree rotation when converting between matrix and raster, but I'm also finding the need to add flips into the code to get the right outcome.  The workflow is a bit tricky so I've made it into a function to show how the outcomes relate to input variables.  To demonstrate:

```
require(raster)
require(akima)
require(OpenStreetMap)
require(rgl)

wgs84 = '+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84'

plot_3d_tile = function(z, xlims, ylims, zscale=1, zoom, crs, plot_rasters=F, ...){
  # specify raster's spatial info
  extent(z) = c(xlims, ylims); crs(z) = crs

  # extend range slightly to crop back to rect after reproj
  osm_x = extendrange(r=xlims); osm_y = extendrange(r=ylims)

  # get OSM map tile & reproject to wgs84
  m = raster(openproj(openmap(c(osm_y[2],osm_x[1]), c(osm_y[1],osm_x[2]), zoom=zoom)))
  m = crop(flip(m,'y'), extent(z))             # FLIPPED
  if(plot_rasters) plotRGB(m)

  # coerce to lists of points for akima::interp
  pts_m = rasterToPoints(m); pts_z = rasterToPoints(z)

  # resizes z to match tile
  intp = interp(x=pts_z[,1], y=pts_z[,2], z=pts_z[,3], 
                xo=unique(pts_m[,1]), yo=unique(pts_m[,2]))

  # get matrix of interpolated z values and convert back to spatial
  z2 = flip(raster(apply(intp$z, 1, rev)),'y') # FLIPPED AND ROTATED
  cat("dimensions match? ", dim(z2) == dim(raster(m)))    # check dimensions match up
  extent(z2) = extent(xlims, ylims); crs(z2) = crs  # spatialise
  if(plot_rasters) plot(z2, asp=T)
  pts_z2 = rasterToPoints(z2)

  # create hex colour vector from tile values
  col_data = getValues(m)
  cols = rgb(col_data[,1], col_data[,2], col_data[,3], maxColorValue = 255)

  # plot 3d extruded map tile
  rgl.open(); bg3d("white")
  rgl.surface(unique(pts_z2[,1]), unique(pts_z2[,2]), pts_z2[,3]*zscale, 
              color=cols, specular="black",  back="lines", asp=T, ...)
  results <<- list(z=z, z2=z2, m=m, intp=intp, pts_m=pts_m, pts_z=pts_z, pts_z2=pts_z2)
}

z1 = raster(volcano)
xlims = c(-0.24, -0.1)
ylims = c(51.4, 51.58)
```

Now to test it:

```
plot_3d_tile(z1, xlims, ylims, zscale=1/3000, zoom=9, crs=wgs84)
```

[image]

```
plot_3d_tile(z1, xlims, ylims, zscale=1/3000, zoom=10, crs=wgs84)
```

[image]

```
plot_3d_tile(z1, xlims, ylims, zscale=1/3000, zoom=11, crs=wgs84)
```

[image]

As you can see, what starts out looking nice gets progressively warped as the OSM zoom level increases.  I suspect I've got something wrong as far as the flips and rotations are concerned, but this is the closest combination I've achieved so far.  A specific problem I know but the code might be useful to others so I'm posting in here.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey stop manupilating my title

Comment: Nice code!  Have you tried plotting *just* the zoomed raster images of your map image, to see what they look like prior to "draping" onto the 3D landscape?  (My highly trained eyeball suspects that the rows of pixels may be getting remapped, as would happen if e.g. a 100x100 array were written to a 105xN array)

Comment: You may be right, although I have checked the dimensions match. I've added argument `plot_rasters` so this will optionally happen automatically. Try with `plot_3d_tile(.. plot_rasters=T)` I've also added a line to output the function's main elements in a list called 'results' to make things easier.

Answer (score 3):

I've figured out a workaround.  Instead of feeding the colour info into `rgl.surface` it's possible to give a png to its `texture` argument.  This probably means my code to make the surface raster match the tile's dimensions is a bit redundant, although it might still make for smoother interpolation if the surface is much lower resolution.  The working function:

[image]

```
plot_3d_tile = function(z, xlims, ylims, zscale=1, zoom, crs, plot_rasters=F, ...){
  # specify raster's spatial info
  extent(z) = c(xlims, ylims); crs(z) = crs
  if(plot_rasters) plot(z, asp=T, main='z')

  # extend range slightly to crop back to rect after reproj
  osm_x = extendrange(r=xlims); osm_y = extendrange(r=ylims)

  # get OSM map tile & reproject to wgs84
  m = raster(openproj(openmap(c(osm_y[2],osm_x[1]), c(osm_y[1],osm_x[2]), zoom=zoom)))
  m = crop(flip(m,'y'), extent(z))             # FLIPPED
  if(plot_rasters) plotRGB(m, asp=T, main='m')
  png('plot.png', width=ncol(m), height=nrow(m))
  plotRGB(m)
  dev.off()

  # coerce to lists of points for akima::interp
  pts_m = rasterToPoints(m); pts_z = rasterToPoints(z)

  # resizes z to match tile
  intp = interp(x=pts_z[,1], y=pts_z[,2], z=pts_z[,3], 
                xo=unique(pts_m[,1]), yo=unique(pts_m[,2]))

  # get matrix of interpolated z values and convert back to spatial
  z2 = raster(apply(intp$z, 1, rev)) # ROTATED
  cat("dimensions match? ", dim(z2) == dim(raster(m)))    # check dimensions match up
  extent(z2) = extent(xlims, ylims); crs(z2) = crs  # spatialise
  if(plot_rasters) plot(z2, asp=T, main='z2')
  pts_z2 = rasterToPoints(z2)

  # plot 3d extruded map tile
  bg3d("white")
  rgl.surface(unique(pts_z2[,1]), unique(pts_z2[,2]), pts_z2[,3]*zscale, 
              texture='plot.png', specular="black",  back="lines", asp=T, ...)
  results <<- list(z=z, z2=z2, m=m, intp=intp, pts_m=pts_m, pts_z=pts_z, pts_z2=pts_z2)
}

rgl.open()

plot_3d_tile(z1, xlims, ylims, zscale=1/3000, zoom=12, crs=wgs84, plot_rasters=T)
```